# My list don't accept greek characters in C#

Tags: c#, list, file

I had create a source code in C# which take each line of a txt document and put it in a list. After that i am trying to show them inside a listbox but i get unknown symbols for greek characters. Here is my code :

```
 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        const string f = "TextFile1.txt";

        // 1
        // Declare new List.
        List<string> lines = new List<string>();

        // 2
        // Use using StreamReader for disposing.
        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(f))
        {
            // 3
            // Use while != null pattern for loop
            string line;
            while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                // 4
                // Insert logic here.
                // ...
                // "line" is a line in the file. Add it to our List.
                lines.Add(line);
            }
        }

        // 5
        // Print out all the lines.
        foreach (string s in lines)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(s);
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }
```

My TextFile1.txt :

Hello!
Γεία σου!

And the result in listbox is :

Hello!
???? ???!

How i could make it to accept greek characters?

Comment: Might be the font being used not having those characters?

Comment: Which encoding was specified for the file when it was created? I'm pretty sure this isn't the fault of the listbox.

Comment: No, because this font i had use it many times with greek text.

Comment: I change the enconding of the text document and everything is perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You need to either specify the encoding in the constructor of `StreamReader` explicitly, or make sure the file itself specifies the correct encoding. Without specifying, `StreamReader` will try to automatically detect the encoding of the file.

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143456(v=vs.110).aspx:

> The StreamReader object attempts to detect the encoding by looking at
>   the first three bytes of the stream.

It checks the first 3 bytes of the file which should specify the encoding using a byte order mark, but if the encoding specified in the file is wrong you can override it using the `StreamReader` constructor. You will also need to specify the option in the StreamReader constructor to not try to attempt to read the byte order mark if it is present and incorrect. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/akzyzwh9(v=vs.110).aspx.